# image of integer in $(Z/p^nZ)^\times$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

This is a homework problem, I don't think I understand what the problem is saying.

Let $ p $ be an odd prime and $ n \ge 1 $ an integer. Prove that if $ a $ is an integer such that $ a-1 $ is divisible by $ p $ but it is not divisible by$  p^2 $ then the image of $ a $ in the multiplicative group of $ Z/p^nZ $ is $ p^{n-1} $.

Say $p=7$, $a=8$, then  $ 8 $ is an integer such that $ 8-1=7 $ is divisible by $ 7 $ but it is not divisible by$  7^2=49 $, then according to the problem, the image of $8$ in $(Z/7^2Z)^\times$ is $7$.... but $7 $ is not even in $(Z/7^2Z)^\times$.

Please help me understand what the problem is saying.

The problem in its official form (by the professor) is attached below
[image]

Comment: There indeed is something wrong with the problem. Are you sure you've copied it correctly? Perhaps it was meant to ask about the order of $a$?

Comment: @Wojowu I have attached an image of the original problem, please take a look.

Comment: It very much seems to me like the problem is misphrased, I would recommend you ask your professor about this in person or via email.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks,I will do that. I was worry that I might be missing something obvious, so that I post it here first

Comment: Don't worry. Missing something obvious is something one should always consider, but it was not the case this time :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem should read "the ... order of the .... image of $a$ is $p^{n-1}$".

It that case, then one possible method is by induction.(but that's not the point of this post)

Please don't post solution (in case you want to) until next week, as this is a homework problem.